# Get multiple files in params (Controller) - Grails

Tags: file, grails, parameters

I have an input and i want to get all the info of the files but i only get the first File.

HTML:

```
input class="btn btn-default" type="file" required name="quotationFiles" multiple onchange="updateValues()"
```

CONTROLLER:

```
def quotationFiles = params.quotationFiles
```

```
List<LinkedHashMap> quotationFilesList = new LinkedList<>()
        quotationFiles.each { file ->
                CommonsMultipartFile quotationFile = file
                Map quotationFilePrev = ["name"     : quotationFile.fileItem.fileName,
                                             "mimeType" : quotationFile.fileItem.contentType,
                                             "size"     : quotationFile.size,
                                             "createdBy": SecUser.findByFromozzUser(FromozzUser.get(springSecurityService.currentUserId)).id,
                                             "data"     : quotationFile.getBytes().encodeAsBase64().toString(), "extension": quotationFile.fileItem.contentType.split('/')[1]]
                quotationFilesList.add(quotationFilePrev)
        }
```

in params.quotationFiles i get the first File and not the others. Please help

[Results in quotationFiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4xdB.png)

Comment: Does `request.getFiles("quotationFiles")` work?

Comment: so sending multiple files is not ideal. If you want to do this you have to reference the files as a list (from what I remember. Like File[0], File[1],File[2]. At least thats what I remember

Comment: I would suggest either packing them in a zip or sending as a single file.